# PHP different php.ini in browser and terminal

Tags: php, include-path, php-include

I'm trying to run some phpUnit tests in phpstorm and I faced a problem

```
PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Money' not found in ...
```

As I asumed my include paths are different when I run script in browser and in terminal.
I tried to echo my include path in browser and in terminal:

```
echo get_include_path();
```

And I got different result. Also when I configure php interpreters in phpstorm settings the dialog, it shows different *.ini configuration files. How can I make terminal run the same php as browser uses?

Comment: Can't you just adjust the ini for CLI to fit your needs?